# How to form count matrix from occurrence of combination using Python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I run into such a coding problem.

Given a data frame with column name ('col1','col2') just like the picture below shown

Dataframe:

[image]

Here, the variables of the column 'col1' and 'col2' are categorical data. I want to form a matrix with each entry counting the number of rows for a specific choice of col1 and of col2. For example, the number of rows such that Column 'col1' equal to '1' and Column 'col2' equal to '1'. (Line 316 in the picture shown)

I got a very large dataset. col1 and col2 both have 1000 different values. If I use a double for loop it would be very slow. Is there a faster way to do so?

I know that `.groupby(by=['col1','col2']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()` would give a sparse representation of the matrix.

Example:

[image]

However, it is not the form I want.

Comment: Is this `tmp.groupby(by=['col1','col2']).size().to_frame('count')` not what you want? what output are you looking for?

Comment: @XXavier As shown in the picture, I want a matrix as shown in line 316.

Comment: This is `tmp.groupby(by=['col1','col2']).size().to_frame('count')` giving you the output you want but instead of dataframe you want it to a matrix? `df.as_matrix()` or `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: @XXavier Yes. I want a matrix. Some entries of the matrix will be zero because the count of some combination will be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(tmp['col1'], tmp['col2'])
```

Output:

```
col2  1  2
col1      
1     1  3
2     1  1
```

Note: 'col1' and 'col2' are index labels.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I want.